# Indefinite integration and summation on Taylor series form $n=-\infty$ to $\infty$

Tags: integration, summation, soft-question, taylor-expansion

I'm wondering about some possibility to modify Taylor series, due to it's pragmatic implication on operator of indefinite integration and summation.

Let's expand Taylor series to the form $f(x)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{f^{(n)}(0)x^n}{n!}$.

Because for negative integers $n$, $\frac{1}{n!} =0$, series at the end is equal to $f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{f^{(n)}(0)x^n}{n!}$

**Indefinite integration**

$F(x)+C_1=\int f(x)dx= \int \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{f^{(n)}(0)x^n}{n!} dx =\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{f^{(n)}(0)x^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}+C_2$

If we choose $C_1=C_2$ and notice that for negative integers $n$, $\frac{1}{n!} =0$ we get true equation

$ F(x)= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{f^{(n-1)}(0)x^{n}}{n!}$

**Indefinite summation**

$\stackrel{\text{*}}{F} (x)+C_1=\sum\limits_{x}f(x)=\sum\limits_{x} \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{f^{(n)}(0)x^n}{n!}=-\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{f^{(n)}(0)\zeta(-n,x)}{n!}+C_2 $

If we choose $C_1=C_2$ and notice that for negative integers $n$, $\frac{1}{n!} =0$ we get true equation

$\stackrel{\text{*}}{F} (x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{f^{(n-1)}(0)B_n(x)}{n!}$

Is it sufficient opservation to say's that $f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{f^{(n)}(0)x^n}{n!}$ is just reduced version of $f(x)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{f^{(n)}(0)x^n}{n!}$?